# Pagination script efficiency and performance

Tags: php, performance, algorithm, pagination

I had to do a pagination script where I would have to pay special attention to perfomance, security and algorithm. I came up with the following code:

```
<?php

class Paginador{

public $current_page;       // current page
public $total_pages;        // total
public $boundaries = 1;         // pages to link in the beggining and in the end
public $around = 1;             // pages to link before and after the current

public $pageArray = array();    // array com toda a informação a paginar


function __construct( $current_page, $total_pages, $boundaries = 1, $around = 1){
    $this->current_page = $current_page;
    $this->total_pages = $total_pages;
    $this->boundaries = $boundaries;
    $this->around = $around;
}

function __destruct(){
    $this->current_page = 0;
    $this->total_pages = 0;
    $this->boundaries = 0;
    $this->around = 0;
}

function setCurrentPage( $newValue ){
    $this->current_page = $newValue;
    return $this;
}

function setTotalPages( $newValue ){
    $this->total_pages = $newValue;
    return $this;
}

function setBoundaries( $newValue ){
    $this->boundaries = $newValue;
    return $this;
}

function setAround( $newValue ){
    $this->around = $newValue;
    return $this;
}

function generateLeftBoundaries(){
    if ( $this->boundaries + $this->around > $this->current_page ) {
        $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( 1 , $this->current_page ) );
    } else {
        if ( $this->boundaries > 0 ) {
            $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( 1, 1 + ( $this->boundaries - 1 ) ) );
        }

        if ( $this->around > 0 ) {
            $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( $this->current_page - $this->around, $this->current_page ) );
        }
    }
}

function generateRightBoundaries() {
    if ( $this->boundaries + $this->around + $this->current_page > $this->total_pages ) {
        $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( $this->current_page, $this->total_pages ) );
    } else {    
        if ( $this->around > 0 ) {
            $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( $this->current_page, $this->current_page + $this->around ) );
        }
        if ( $this->boundaries > 0 ) {
            $this->pageArray = array_merge( $this->pageArray, $this->populateArray( $this->total_pages - ( $this->boundaries - 1 ), $this->total_pages ) );
        }
    }   
}

function populateArray( $start, $end ) {
    $output = array();
    for ( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
        $output[] = $i;
    }
    return $output;
}

function paginate(){

    //create the structure
    $this->pageArray = array();
    $this->generateLeftBoundaries();
    $this->pageArray[] = $this->current_page;
    $this->generateRightBoundaries();
    $this->pageArray[] = $this->total_pages;
    $this->pageArray = array_values( array_unique( $this->pageArray ) );

    //now print the pagination array
    $pages = $this->pageArray;

    $items = count( $pages );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $items; $i++ ) {
        $current_page = $pages[ $i ];
        echo $current_page . ' ';
        if ( ( $i + 1 ) < $items
                && $pages[ $i + 1 ] != ( $current_page + 1 ) ) {
            echo '...';
        }
    }

}

}

?>
```

This code currently works as intended, my question is about performance, legibility and security. How can I improve this code to be more efficient, and easier to understand. If you can state the reasons why it would be great.
Thx in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - it would be more appropriately asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

For some performance and security please set the visibility of you're methods. So for example:

```
public function setCurrentPage( $newValue ){
    $this->current_page = $newValue;
    return $this;
}
```

Or

```
private function setCurrentPage( $newValue ){
    $this->current_page = $newValue;
    return $this;
}
```

Or protected if you use packages.

You can check the type of the variable like in every other modern programming language:

```
function setBoundaries( $newValue ){
    $this->boundaries = $newValue;
    return $this;
}
```

You can read more about typehinting in php http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Use encapsulation in you're class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29
So make you're variables private.

And don't return $this; in you're setters. I really don't know why you want that.

Comment: It's setters... it shouldn't return anything right?